# How to make launching screen to second tab

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I have created an tab bar application having 3 tab.

When I am launching the app the the first tab is shown to me first.

But I want to make second tab as launching screen.
The tab order will remain same. when I will open the app, it should show me the middle tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will enable you in choosing the default tab at start up

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabbar controller has a property which selects particular tab: *selectedIndex*.

Usage:  `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

**Note:** *Index for various tabs starts from 0, i.e. First tab has index 0, second tab has 2 and so on*

Please mark correct answer if helps :)